# Update Python Environment Variable to be reused across all python codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

I am trying to update environment variable to reuse same values for some variables across different Python Jobs. I found option of updating it using os.environ but this updates only for local session , it does not persist these values permanently. Can someone please suggest how to update Environment Variables in Python permanently.

I tried below code but it works only for current session:

```py
os.environ['API_USER'] = 'username'
os.environ['API_PASSWORD'] = 'secret'
```

Comment: Have you considered to store the environment configuration into an external file e.g. yaml file.

Comment: Can't be done with environment variables.  Variables are inherited from the parent process and can only be changed in the current process.  When current process exits, the changes are lost.

Comment: is there any other way to store common values in a configuration file and use across multiple Python codes?

Comment: _"is there any other way to store common values in a configuration file"_ - open a file, store data in it, open the file in another process, read from it...

Comment: when I print os.environ, I get dictionary containing different parameters. I am thinking there might be a way to add some more elements in this dictionary permanently . is it not true?

Comment: "is it not true?" No, that isn't true. At least not without using something like a config file that all your python programs read. Alternatively, put the env vars in */etc/environment*. It's hard to provide good advice because you didn't say what OS you're using and your requirements aren't clear.